# Can Vaadin + Spring Security act only as the oauth2 user agent not the client?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, vaadin, spring-security-oauth2

The Oauth2 authorization code flow defines roles as they are shown in the top of the following graphic.
[image: Oauth Authorization Code flow]

I allready have a client app writen with spring security and multiple resource servers.
Is it posible for a Vaadin app to only act as the UserAgent? I.e. have one java app which serves a Vaadin frontend but passes the login requests to another client app written in java with spring security (or any other oauth2 compliant program for that matter)?
I think read that it is favourable to separate front- and backend. Sofar I have only found tutorials which configure the java vaadin app as the Client App.
I.e. something like this in the applicaiton.yaml

```
spring:
   security:
      oauth2:
        client:
           registration:
              keycloak:
                client-id: 
                client-secret: 
                authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
                redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
                scope: 
        provider:
          keycloak:
             issuerUri:
```

And a security configuration like so

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Client()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
   }
}
```

Alternatively:
Is it possible for a resource server to make API requests to another resource server? I.e. configure a web client / oauth2Client instance which can make authorized rest-requests?

Comment: I cannot understand this sentence `Is it posible for a Vaadin app to only act as the UserAgent?`, Do you want to create the authentication UI part of your solution with Vaadin?

Comment: Regarding to this `Is it possible for a resource server to make API requests to another resource server?`: I can say it depends on your architecture. In a Microservice architecture, each service registers itself in a registry and other services can find it through the registry. I think reading about Microservice architecture can be helpful.

Comment: So many applications would never reach to that point where they need to separate UI from backend in essence of separate codebase and separate deployment for huge clustering and load-balancing purposes, and the gain from those separation may or may not worth solving other problems it raises.

Comment: First comment: 
I don't want to implement the authentication UI myselft. I want the vaadin app to act as if it was "just frontend, like angular". i.e. don't receive the auth code and trade it for access codes, but pass the auth code on to my exising java app.
Second and Third:
I read about microservice architecutre but thought it was an overkill as you say in comment three, but maybe it's just what I want. But maybe for the time beeing it is sufficient to not split front and backend. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to separate the UI from the backend in the essence of the separate codebase and separate deployment for huge clustering and load-balancing purposes you may consider a Microservice architecture.

In a Microservice architecture, each service (including the OAuth service and maybe the UI itself) registers itself in a service registry, so it is possible for other services to find and call each other through that registry. This is a very abstract explanation and for implementing such architectures and you should dive deeper into the details.

So many applications would never reach that point where they need to separate UI from backend, and the gain from that separation may or may not worth solving other problems it raises.

Anyway, Vaadin Fusion introduced recently as an alternative to the pure Java version (or the Java + HTML Template version), to create UI applications by Typescript and HTML. So the UI resides completely on the browser somehow similar to Vue, Angular, and React.

Although Vaadin Fusion designed in a way that can automatically connect to backend services within the same project, I believe you can do what you want by applying some tweaks for calling other backend services (such as OAuth or your existing java apps). However, you should deal with some other problems such as handling CORS or user sessions, etc. (Which also are the existing issues when you use other frontend frameworks and libraries).

You can find out more about Vaadin Fusion [here](https://vaadin.com/fusion). For a quick start, you may also want to see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKjwDfPBzIk&feature=youtu.be) short video.